# Getting the correct data from an array after a query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a sql statement....

```
"SELECT o.orderID, p.productID, p.name, o.qty, p.mouldID FROM products AS p INNER JOIN orderedProducts AS o ON o.productID = p.productID WHERE o.orderID = '$id'";
```

when I use it in phpmyadmin to test it, it looks like this (I use the ID 56)

```
        __________________________________________
       |orderID|productID|name       |qty |mouldID|
       |56     |11       |newproduct |2000|4      |
       |56     |12       |newproduct2|10  |5      |
       |56     |13       |newproduct3|5   |6      |
```

But the array that is spit out is:

```
Array ( [0] => 56 [orderID] => 56 [1] => 11 [productID] => 11 [2] => newproduct [name] => newproduct [3] => 2000 [qty] => 2000 [4] => 4 [mouldID] => 4 )
```

This is not the data I want, so I tried seeing what happens if I put it into a table

it returns

```
0         | 56
orderID   | 56
1         |  11
productID |  11
2         | newproduct
name      | newproduct
3         |  2000
qty       |  2000
4         |  4
mouldID   |  4
```

Clearly something is going wrong...

I use `mysql_fetch_array` to get the data from the database into the array...is this perhaps what I am doing wrong?

Basically I want it to look like the first table that the database returns.

Any ideas...thanks!

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` only returns one row at a time. You have to call it in a loop to get all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql_fetch_XXX()` functions just return the next row, not all the results. If you want an array of all rows, you have to construct it with a loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $results[] = $row;
}
var_dump($results);
```